# Python. Деревья. JSON stringify

Tags: python, json, строки, дерево

Задача реализовать функцию stringify(), похожую на JSON.stringify(), но со следующими отличиями:

- ключи и строковые значения должны быть без кавычек;
- строчка (линия) в строке заканчивается самим значением, без запятой.

Синтаксис:

stringify(value[, replacer[, spaces_count]])

Параметры:

- value Значение, преобразуемое в строку.
- replacer, необязательный Строка – отступ для ключа; Значение по
  умолчанию – один пробел.
- spacesCount, необязательный Число – количество повторов отступа
  ключа. Значение по умолчанию – 1.

Пример выполнения:

```
>>> data = { "hello": "world", "is": True, "nested": { "count": 5 } }
>>> stringify(data)  # то же самое что stringify(data, ' ', 1)
{
  hello: world
  is: True
  nested: {
   count: 5
  }
}
```

В моем коде возникает проблема с приведением строки к требуемому виду. В получаемом результате нет фигурных скобок ({}).

```
def stringify(value, replacer = ' ', space_count = 1):
    result = ''
    for el in value:
        if isinstance(value[el], dict):
            val = stringify(value[el], replacer, space_count)
            result += f'{replacer*space_count}{el}: {val}\n'
        else:
            result += f'{replacer*space_count}{el}: {value[el]}\n'
    return result
```

Каким образом можно реализовать требуемый вывод строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если всё же хотите ручками, без использования модуля json, то вот:

```
def stringify(value, replacer = ' ', space_count = 1, _lvl = 1):
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        result = '{\n'
        for el, val in value.items():
            result += f'{replacer*space_count*_lvl}{el}: '
            result += stringify(val, replacer, space_count, _lvl+1) + '\n'
        result += replacer*space_count*(_lvl-1) + '}'
    else:
        result = str(value)
    return result
    
data = { "hello": "world", "is": True, "nested": { "count": 5 , "sub-nested": {} } }
print(stringify(data, space_count=4))
```

```
{
    hello: world
    is: True
    nested: {
        count: 5
        sub-nested: {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

вот так что ли?

```
import json


class JSONEncoderEx(json.JSONEncoder):

    def __init__(self, *, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, sort_keys, indent, separators, default):
        super().__init__(skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii, check_circular=check_circular,
                         allow_nan=allow_nan, sort_keys=sort_keys, indent=indent, separators=separators,
                         default=default)
        self.item_separator = ""


json.encoder.encode_basestring = lambda x: json.encoder.py_encode_basestring(x)[1:-1]
json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii = lambda x: json.encoder.py_encode_basestring_ascii(x)[1:-1]


data = {"hello": "world", "is": True, "nested": {"count": 5}}
s = json.dumps(data, cls=JSONEncoderEx, indent=2)
print(s)
# {
#   hello: world
#   is: True
#   nested: {
#    count: 5
#   }
# }
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, но задача не подразумевает использование классов.